# Inspecting chart.js chart object

Tags: object, charts, chart.js

I have code to create a simple line chart using the chart.js library.

```js
'use strict'

const ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d')

let config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [1, 4, 1, 5, 9],
            },
        ],
    },
}

let chart = new Chart(ctx, config)

console.log(chart)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support Canvas</canvas>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question concerns the inspection of the created object. A structure of many elements appears in the console.
[image]
I would like to know what the first element - "**$context:**" - is, what is its purpose, what are its uses and why is it infinitely nested?

Comment: That is an *undocumented* property. Due to the nature of javascript, objects expose both API items and internal properties (the recent private class features is not widely used). You will not find a document describing this property, nor does it make any sense for someone to write one, mostly because there's no guarantee that this object will keep its features in future versions of chart.js.

Comment: However, the fact that it is exposed, makes it useful for implementing "hacky" solutions (tied to specific versions of chart.js) through handlers and plugins. The property names of the `$context` object  (or other properties that start with an underscore) are rather self-explanatory and when in doubt one has to consult the source code of chart.js. But the mindset can't be that of learning the meaning of every property but rather that of identifying the property that hold the information needed to solve a specific problem.